# compare two select in two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to return ***Cities*** with international flights departures

I know this is not correct, but this is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
    flight.departurecity 
FROM 
    flight 
INNER JOIN 
    airport ON flight.departurecity = airport.city 
WHERE 
    (SELECT airport.nation WHERE flight.departurecity = airport.city) != 
        (SELECT airport.nation WHERE flight.arrivalcity = airport.city)
```

Airport table:

[image: airport table]

Flight table:

[image: flight table]

Comment: Can you please put the text of the data here instead of linking images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    flight.departurecity 
FROM 
    flight 
INNER JOIN 
    airport a1 ON flight.departurecity = a1.city 
INNER JOIN 
    airport a2 ON flight.arrivalcity = a2.city 
WHERE 
    a1.nation != a2.nation;
```

Corrected and modified version what Gordon Linoff meant to suggest I guess:

```
select a.*
from airport a
where exists (select *
              from flight f join
                   airport a2 on f.arrivalCity = a2.city
              where f.departureCity = a.city
                    and a2.nation <> a.nation
             );
```

Comment: @Laurentius Welcome. You would want to have DISTINCT since a city would have multiple departures.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go for:

```
select a.*
from airport a
where exists (select 1
              from flight f join
                   airport a2
              where f2.arrivalcity = a2.city and
                    f2.departurecity = a.city and
                    a2.nation <> a.nation
             );
```

Note that this does not require `select distinct`, unless you really want a list of cities rather than just airports.  So, it should be much faster than the double `join` version.

Comment: Correcting the typos this would likely to return all cities. Maybe you meant select a.*
from airport a
where exists (select *
              from flight f join
                   airport a2 on f.arrivalCity = a2.city
              where f.departureCity = a.city
                    and a2.nation <> a.nation
             );   adding this too.